# Почему этот запрос SQL удаляет все записи игнорируя время (kohana Query Builder)

Tags: php, kohana

Вот запрос, который работает корректно (нужно удалить все записи в таблице **url_password** если они находятся в базе больше 5 минут)

```
   DELETE FROM `url_password` WHERE `url_password_date` < NOW() - INTERVAL 5 MINUTE
```

При попытке сделать этот запрос в kohane через  Query Builder удаляется все записи не смотря на время. Вот этот запрос:

```
 DB::delete($this->_url_password)
          ->where('url_password_date', '<',  'NOW() - INTERVAL 5 MINUTE' )->execute();
```

Где может быть ошибка? Заранее благодарю за помощь.

Answer (score 1):

С Коханой не знаком, бегло прочитал про построитель запросов.

1. что у тебя в $this->_url_password?
2. Попробуй сделать такой запрос

   DB::delete($this->_url_password)
             ->where('url_password_date', '<',  DB::expr('(NOW() - INTERVAL 5 MINUTE)')->execute();

Comment: 1) Таблица в базе
2) Да абсолютно верно спасибо! Вот бы мне так бегло посмотреть и все правильно делать))